# Brick Breaker help. circles, paddles, and awkward bouncing

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, geometry

I've written a simple brick breaker game in OpenGL. The ball is a 2D circle drawn using :

```
for (float angle = 0; angle < (10); angle+=0.01)
 {
     glVertex2f((x_pos + sin(angle) * RADIUS), (y_pos + (cos(angle)) * RADIUS));
 }
```

This causes distortion when the game is changed to fullscreen. RADIUS is defined as 0.025 .
I need help in making the paddle movements smooth as well.
Also, if you play the game a couple of times, you'll notice that towards the extreme left, when the ball hits the paddle, it rises to a certain height and then bounces back down.
Full code:

```
#include <GL/openglut.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#define RADIUS 0.025
#define SPEED  0.001
int WIDTH = 900;
int HEIGHT =  650;
int RATIO = WIDTH/HEIGHT;
bool show[5][10];
float x_brick[4][9];
float y_brick[4][9];
float P_XPOS = 0;
float P_YPOS = -0.8;
bool phit_center = false , phit_corner = false;
bool game_over = false;
bool RIGHT = 1,LEFT = 0,UP = 1,DOWN = 0;
bool started = false;
float x_pos = 0,y_pos = -0.75;
bool hit = false;
int lives  = 3;
using namespace std;
void b_draw()
{
      glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      for(int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
      {
              for(int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
              {
                      if(show[b][a] == 1)
                      {
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a],y_brick[b][a]);
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a],y_brick[b][a] - 0.10); 
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a]+0.2,y_brick[b][a] - 0.10);
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a]+0.2,y_brick[b][a]);  
                      }
              }
      }
      glEnd();
}
void c_draw()
{
     glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
     glVertex2f(x_pos,y_pos);
     for (float angle = 0; angle < (10); angle+=0.01)
     {
         glVertex2f((x_pos + sin(angle) * RADIUS), (y_pos + (cos(angle)) * RADIUS));
     }
     glEnd();
}
bool b_hit()
{
     hit = false;
     int flag = 1;
     for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
     {
             for(int b =0; b < 4; b++)
             {
                     if(x_pos >= x_brick[b][a] && x_pos <= x_brick[b][a] + 0.2)
                     {
                              if(y_pos <= y_brick[b][a] && y_pos >= y_brick[b][a] - 0.1)
                              {
                                       if(show[b][a] == 1)
                                       {
                                                     show[b][a] = 0;
                                                     flag = 0;
                                                     hit = true;
                                                     break;
                                       }
                              }
                     }
             }
             if(flag == 0)
                     break;
     }
     return hit;
}
bool crashed()
{
     if(y_pos < P_YPOS - 0.05)
              return true;
     else return false;;
}
void p_hit()
{
     phit_corner = false;
     phit_center = false;
     if(x_pos <= P_XPOS + 0.13 && x_pos >= P_XPOS - 0.13)
     {
              if(y_pos <= P_YPOS)
              {
                       phit_center = true;
              }
     }
     else if((x_pos >= P_XPOS + 0.13 && x_pos <= P_XPOS + 0.2) || (x_pos <= P_XPOS - 0.13 && x_pos >= P_XPOS - 0.2))
     {
               if(y_pos <= P_YPOS)
               {
                        phit_corner = true;
               }
     }
}
 void c_move()
 {
      if(UP && RIGHT)
      {
           x_pos += (SPEED);
           y_pos += (SPEED);       
      }
      if(UP && LEFT)
      {
            x_pos -= (SPEED);
            y_pos += (SPEED);
      }
      if(DOWN && RIGHT)
      {
              x_pos += (SPEED);
              y_pos -= (SPEED);
      }
      if(DOWN && LEFT)
      {
              x_pos -= (SPEED);
              y_pos -= (SPEED);
      }
      b_hit();
      if(x_pos >= (RATIO-RADIUS))
      {
               RIGHT = 0;
               LEFT = 1;
      }
      else if(x_pos <= (-RATIO+RADIUS))
      {
           RIGHT = 1;
           LEFT = 0;
      }
      if(y_pos >= (RATIO-RADIUS) || hit )
      {
                  UP = 0;
                  DOWN = 1;
      }
      else if(y_pos <= (-RATIO+RADIUS) || hit )
      {
           UP = 1;
           DOWN = 0;
      }
      p_hit();
      if(phit_center)
      {
                     DOWN = 0;
                     UP = 1;
      }
      if(phit_corner)
      {
                     if(LEFT)
                     {
                             LEFT = 0;
                             RIGHT = 1;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         RIGHT = 0;
                         LEFT = 1;
                     }
                     UP = 1;
                     DOWN = 0;
      }
}
void p_draw()
{
     glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                      glVertex2f(P_XPOS-0.2,P_YPOS);
                      glVertex2f(P_XPOS+0.2,P_YPOS);
                      glVertex2f(P_XPOS+0.2,P_YPOS-0.05);
                      glVertex2f(P_XPOS-0.2,P_YPOS-0.05);
     glEnd();
}

void BallLoop()
{
     glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0);
     glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
     glLoadIdentity();
     c_draw();
     b_draw();
     p_draw();
     glFlush();
     if(started)
                c_move();
     if(crashed())
     {           
                 x_pos = 0;
                 y_pos = -0.7;
                 started = 0;
                 UP = 1;
                 RIGHT = 1;
                 DOWN = 0;
                 LEFT = 0;
     }

     glutSwapBuffers();
     glutPostRedisplay();
}
void user_input(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
     if(key == 13)
     started = true;
}
void ArrowKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
     if(key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT && P_XPOS >= -0.8)
      for(float a = 0; a < 0.05; a+= 0.001)
      {
                                      P_XPOS -=0.003;
                                      BallLoop();
      }
     if(key==GLUT_KEY_RIGHT && P_XPOS <= 0.8)
     {
                            for(float a = 0; a < 0.05; a+= 0.001)
                            {
                                      P_XPOS +=0.003;
                                      BallLoop();
                            }
     }
}
void set_xy()
{
    for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
            for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
            {
                    show[a][b] = 1;
            }
    }
    int c = 0;
    for(float a = -0.94; c <= 8; a+=0.21)
    {         

              for(int b = 0; b <= 5; b++)
              {
                      x_brick[b][c] = a;

              }
              c++;
    }
    int d = 0;
    for(float s = 0.99; d <= 3; s-=0.11)
    {
              for(int  r = 0; r < 9; r++)
              {
                       y_brick[d][r] = s;
              }
              d++;
    }
}
void changeSize(int w, int h) 
{

    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;
    RATIO = w/h;
    float ratio = 1.0* w / h;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    BallLoop();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    set_xy();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);                    
    glutCreateWindow("Brick Breaker - By Viraj");
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(BallLoop);
    glutKeyboardFunc(user_input);
    glutSpecialFunc(ArrowKeys);
    glutMainLoop(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For smooth movement, check this out: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html The axis has an exponential increase so when you push the button down then up again suddenly, your paddle doesn't move as much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of people run into this kind of issue, because they base their code on badly written tutorials. One key mistake is to do the projection matrix setup in the reshape handler. In any serious OpenGL application, games including, you will switch the projection several times during rendering – for HUDs, minimaps, GUI elements etc.

Instead you set projection in the display handler, right before you need that projection.  Also you missed to set the projection matrix at all, you only set the viewport - close, but not enough. I'd not call the display handler `Ball_Loop`, but well, here's how I'd modify it:

```
void BallLoop()
{
     const int   win_width  = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
     const int   win_height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
     const float win_aspect = (float)win_width/(float)win_height;

     glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0);
     glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);
     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     glOrtho(-aspect, aspect, -1, 1, -1, 1); /* those ortho limits should match your game logic */

     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
     glLoadIdentity();
     c_draw();
     b_draw();
     p_draw();
     glFlush();
     if(started)
                c_move();
     if(crashed())
     {           
                 x_pos = 0;
                 y_pos = -0.7;
                 started = 0;
                 UP = 1;
                 RIGHT = 1;
                 DOWN = 0;
                 LEFT = 0;
     }

     glutSwapBuffers();
     glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

---

**EDIT** *fully fixed and playable brickbreaker.cc source code*

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define RADIUS 0.025

#define RATIO (4./3.)

bool show[5][10];
float x_brick[4][9];
float y_brick[4][9];

float paddle_x = 0;
float paddle_y = -0.8;
float paddle_speed = 0;
const float PaddleSpeedFactor = 3.;

bool phit_center = false , phit_corner = false;
bool game_over = false;

float speed_x = 0.;
float speed_y = 0.;

float x_pos = 0,y_pos = -0.75;
int lives  = 3;

float T_last_frame = 0.;

void draw_bricks()
{
      glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      for(int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
      {
              for(int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
              {
                      if(show[b][a] == 1)
                      {
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a],y_brick[b][a]);
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a],y_brick[b][a] - 0.10); 
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a]+0.2,y_brick[b][a] - 0.10);
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a]+0.2,y_brick[b][a]);  
                      }
              }
      }
      glEnd();
}

void ball_draw()
{
     glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
     glVertex2f(x_pos,y_pos);
     for (float angle = 0; angle < (10); angle+=0.01)
     {
         glVertex2f((x_pos + sin(angle) * RADIUS), (y_pos + (cos(angle)) * RADIUS));
     }
     glEnd();
}

bool brick_hit()
{
     bool hit = false;
     int flag = 1;
     for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
     {
             for(int b =0; b < 4; b++)
             {
                     if(x_pos >= x_brick[b][a] && x_pos <= x_brick[b][a] + 0.2)
                     {
                              if(y_pos <= y_brick[b][a] && y_pos >= y_brick[b][a] - 0.1)
                              {
                                       if(show[b][a] == 1)
                                       {
                                                     show[b][a] = 0;
                                                     flag = 0;
                                                     hit = true;
                                                     break;
                                       }
                              }
                     }
             }
             if(flag == 0)
                     break;
     }
     return hit;
}

bool crashed()
{
     if(y_pos < paddle_y - 0.05)
              return true;

     return false;
}

void paddle_hit()
{
     phit_corner = false;
     phit_center = false;
     if(x_pos <= paddle_x + 0.13 && x_pos >= paddle_x - 0.13)
     {
              if(y_pos <= paddle_y)
              {
                       phit_center = true;
              }
     }
     else if( (x_pos >= paddle_x + 0.13 && x_pos <= paddle_x + 0.2) || 
                  (x_pos <= paddle_x - 0.13 && x_pos >= paddle_x - 0.2))
     {
               if(y_pos <= paddle_y)
               {
                        phit_corner = true;
               }
     }
}

void paddle_move(float dT)
{

    if(paddle_x < RATIO && paddle_x > -RATIO)
        paddle_x += paddle_speed * PaddleSpeedFactor * dT;

        if( paddle_x > 0.95) {
        paddle_x = 0.95;
        paddle_speed = 0.;
    }

        if( paddle_x < -0.95) {
        paddle_x = -0.95;
        paddle_speed = 0.;
    }

    paddle_speed *= (1. - 0.05);
    if( fabs(paddle_speed) < 0.01 )
        paddle_speed = 0.;
}

void ball_move(float dT)
{
      x_pos += speed_x * dT;
      y_pos += speed_y * dT;

      if( brick_hit() ) {
        speed_y *= -1;
      }

      if( x_pos >= (RATIO-RADIUS) || x_pos <= (-RATIO+RADIUS ) )
      {
        speed_x *= -1;
      }

      if( y_pos >= (1.-RADIUS) )
      {
        speed_y = -1;
      }

      paddle_hit();
      if(phit_center)
      {
        speed_y = 1;
      }
      if(phit_corner)
      {
        speed_x *= -1;
        speed_y = 1;
      }
}

void paddle_draw()
{
     glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                      glVertex2f(paddle_x - 0.2, paddle_y);
                      glVertex2f(paddle_x + 0.2, paddle_y);
                      glVertex2f(paddle_x + 0.2, paddle_y - 0.05);
                      glVertex2f(paddle_x - 0.2, paddle_y - 0.05);
     glEnd();
}

void step_game()
{
     paddle_move(T_last_frame);
     ball_move(T_last_frame);

     if(crashed())
     {
    speed_x = 0;
    speed_y = 0; 
        x_pos = 0;
        y_pos = -0.7;
        paddle_speed = 0;
        paddle_x = 0;
     }

     glutPostRedisplay();
}

void launch_ball()
{
    speed_y = 1.;
    speed_x = 1.;
}

void user_input(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
     if(key == 13)
        launch_ball();
}

void ArrowKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
     if(key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
        paddle_speed = -1.;

     if(key==GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
        paddle_speed = +1.;
}

void set_xy()
{
    for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
            for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++)
            {
                    show[a][b] = 1;
            }
    }
    int c = 0;
    for(float a = -0.94; c <= 8; a+=0.21)
    {         

              for(int b = 0; b <= 5; b++)
              {
                      x_brick[b][c] = a;

              }
              c++;
    }
    int d = 0;
    for(float s = 0.99; d <= 3; s-=0.11)
    {
              for(int  r = 0; r < 9; r++)
              {
                       y_brick[d][r] = s;
              }
              d++;
    }
}

void display()
{
    const int win_width  = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    const int win_height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    const float win_aspect = (float)win_width / (float)win_height;

    glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if(win_aspect > RATIO) {
        glOrtho(-win_aspect, win_aspect, -1., 1., -1., 1.);
    } else {
        glOrtho(-RATIO, RATIO, -RATIO/win_aspect, RATIO/win_aspect, -1., 1.);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glClearColor(0., 0., 1., 1.);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glVertex2f(-RATIO, -1);
        glVertex2f(RATIO, -1);
        glVertex2f(RATIO, 1);
        glVertex2f(-RATIO, 1);
        glEnd();

    draw_bricks();
    paddle_draw();
    ball_draw();

    glutSwapBuffers();

        // GLUT doesn't offer cross plattform timing
        // assume 60Hz refresh rate
        T_last_frame = 1./60.;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    set_xy();

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);

    glutCreateWindow("Brick Breaker - By Viraj");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutKeyboardFunc(user_input);
    glutSpecialFunc(ArrowKeys);

    glutIdleFunc(step_game);

    glutMainLoop(); 

    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2** and just for the sake of completeness, here's a GLFW version

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

#define RADIUS 0.025

#define RATIO (4./3.)

bool show[5][10];
float x_brick[4][9];
float y_brick[4][9];

const float SpeedFactor = 10.;

float paddle_x = 0;
float paddle_y = -0.8;
float paddle_speed = 0;
const float PaddleSpeedFactor = 3.;

bool phit_center = false, phit_corner = false;
bool game_over = false;

float speed_x = 0.;
float speed_y = 0.;

float x_pos;
float y_pos;
int lifes = 0;

void draw_bricks()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
            if (show[b][a] == 1) {
                glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a], y_brick[b][a]);
                glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a], y_brick[b][a] - 0.10);
                glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a] + 0.2,
                       y_brick[b][a] - 0.10);
                glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a] + 0.2, y_brick[b][a]);
            }
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}

void ball_draw()
{
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(x_pos, y_pos);
    for (float angle = 0; angle < (10); angle += 0.01) {
        glVertex2f((x_pos + sin(angle) * RADIUS),
               (y_pos + (cos(angle)) * RADIUS));
    }
    glEnd();
}

bool brick_hit()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
            if (x_pos >= x_brick[b][a]
                && x_pos <= x_brick[b][a] + 0.2) {
                if (y_pos <= y_brick[b][a]
                    && y_pos >= y_brick[b][a] - 0.1) {
                    if (show[b][a] == 1) {
                        show[b][a] = 0;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool crashed()
{
    if (y_pos < paddle_y - 0.05)
        return true;

    return false;
}

void paddle_hit()
{
    phit_corner = false;
    phit_center = false;
    if (x_pos <= paddle_x + 0.13 && x_pos >= paddle_x - 0.13) {
        if (y_pos <= paddle_y) {
            phit_center = true;
        }
    } else if ((x_pos >= paddle_x + 0.13 && x_pos <= paddle_x + 0.2) ||
           (x_pos <= paddle_x - 0.13 && x_pos >= paddle_x - 0.2)) {
        if (y_pos <= paddle_y) {
            phit_corner = true;
        }
    }
}

void paddle_move(float dT)
{

    if (paddle_x < RATIO && paddle_x > -RATIO)
        paddle_x += paddle_speed * PaddleSpeedFactor * dT;

    if (paddle_x > 1.) {
        paddle_x = 1.;
        paddle_speed = 0.;
    }

    if (paddle_x < -1.) {
        paddle_x = -1.;
        paddle_speed = 0.;
    }
}

void ball_move(float dT)
{
    x_pos += speed_x * dT;
    y_pos += speed_y * dT;

    if (brick_hit()) {
        speed_y *= -1;
    }

        if (x_pos >= (RATIO - RADIUS) || x_pos <= (-RATIO + RADIUS)) {
        speed_x *= -1;
    }

    if (y_pos >= (1. - RADIUS)) {
        speed_y = -1;
    }

    paddle_hit();
    if (phit_center) {
        speed_y = 1;
    }
    if (phit_corner) {
        speed_x *= -1;
        speed_y = 1;
    }
}

void paddle_draw()
{
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(paddle_x - 0.2, paddle_y);
    glVertex2f(paddle_x + 0.2, paddle_y);
    glVertex2f(paddle_x + 0.2, paddle_y - 0.05);
    glVertex2f(paddle_x - 0.2, paddle_y - 0.05);
    glEnd();
}

void reset_game()
{
    lifes = 3;
    speed_x = 0;
    speed_y = 0;
    x_pos = 0;
    y_pos = -0.7;
    paddle_speed = 0;
    paddle_x = 0;
}

void step_game(float dT)
{
    if(!lifes)
        return;

    paddle_move(dT * SpeedFactor);
    ball_move(dT * SpeedFactor);

    if (crashed()) {
        lifes--;
        speed_x = 0;
        speed_y = 0;
        x_pos = 0;
        y_pos = -0.7;
    }
}

void launch_ball()
{
    if(!lifes)
        return;

    speed_y = 1.;
    speed_x = 1.;
}

void keyboard(int key, int action)
{
    switch(key) 
    {
    case GLFW_KEY_ENTER:
        launch_ball();
        break;

    case GLFW_KEY_ESC:
        reset_game();
        break;

    case GLFW_KEY_LEFT:
        switch(action) {
        case GLFW_PRESS:
            paddle_speed = -1.;
            break;

        case GLFW_RELEASE:
            paddle_speed = 0;
            break;
        } break;

    case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT:
        switch(action) {
        case GLFW_PRESS:
            paddle_speed = 1.;
            break;

        case GLFW_RELEASE:
            paddle_speed = 0;
            break;
        } break;
    }
}

void set_xy()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
            show[a][b] = 1;
        }
    }
    int c = 0;
    for (float a = -0.94; c <= 8; a += 0.21) {

        for (int b = 0; b <= 5; b++) {
            x_brick[b][c] = a;

        }
        c++;
    }
    int d = 0;
    for (float s = 0.99; d <= 3; s -= 0.11) {
        for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
            y_brick[d][r] = s;
        }
        d++;
    }
}

float display()
{
    int win_width;
    int win_height;
    glfwGetWindowSize(&win_width, &win_height);
    const float win_aspect = (float)win_width / (float)win_height;

    glfwSetTime(0.);

    glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (win_aspect > RATIO) {
        glOrtho(-win_aspect, win_aspect, -1., 1., -1., 1.);
    } else {
        glOrtho(-RATIO, RATIO, -RATIO / win_aspect, RATIO / win_aspect,
            -1., 1.);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glClearColor(0., 0., 1., 1.);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex2f(-RATIO, -1);
    glVertex2f(RATIO, -1);
    glVertex2f(RATIO, 1);
    glVertex2f(-RATIO, 1);
    glEnd();

    draw_bricks();
    paddle_draw();

    ball_draw();

    glfwSwapBuffers();
    return glfwGetTime();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    set_xy();

    if( GL_FALSE == glfwInit() )
        return -1;

    if( GL_FALSE == glfwOpenWindow(800, 600, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW) )
        return -2;

    glfwSetWindowTitle("Viraj's Brick Breaker - GLFW version by datenwolf");
    glfwSetKeyCallback(keyboard);

    reset_game();

    while( glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED) ) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        float const dT = display();
        step_game(dT);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for that :) But it doesnt fix the paddle being a bit jerky and slow.

Comment: @viraj: The paddle being jerky and slow is an issue with your input management. It looks like you're doing the game logic in part in the display function. Not the ideal place to do it. Place the game logic in the idle function, use the input callbacks to set input flags (which keys are de-/pressed, de-/pressed mouse buttons, etc., mouse-move handlers should accumulate movement events) and apply those input flags on the game state. Also measure the time it takes to render and display a frame and use this to advance your game-time. In essence you should not mix render and game logic – fix that.

Comment: Also, I want to render 3 hearts at the bottom. I used equations to plot points and draw a heart shape.
I put that in the diplay function, but it makes things extremely slow.
functions:
mod(x)-sqrt(1-x*x); mod(x)+sqrt(1-x*x);

Comment: @datewolf Should I call the move() functions in the idle or the diplay function?

Comment: @viraj: Idle function, but frankly, GLUT is a suboptimal choice for a framework used for a game. You're facing one of the issues right now: You don't have control about the event loop. In the event callbacks set flags (which keys are de-/pressed) and react in the game logic appropriately. One of the problems you'll be facing is timing between game logic and display. But doing game logic in the display callback will make your game sluggish. Ideally you'd use something like GLFW, do all event handling and game logic in a separate thread, calculating for the next frame in advance.

Comment: I tried calling move in the idle function, but that resulted in the ball only moving when the paddle was stationary. Also, I didnt understand  what you meant by 'measure the time it takes to render and display a frame and use this to advance your game-time'

Comment: @viraj: I fixed your original source code and made is as playable as possible with GLUT. There are still the drawbacks of GLUT keyboard input and the lack of a timer – and frankly I didn't want to introduce plattform dependent code. Switching to GLFW or SFML I suggest.

Comment: @viraj: About those life indicator hearts: You shouldn't evaluate the curve upon drawing. Evaluate it once, generate a mesh and just draw that precalculated mesh. However in your case using small pictures should be easier, because hearts are non-convex shapes, but OpenGL can only draw convex polygons, so you'd have to tesselate it down into convex subshapes.

Comment: @viraj let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1884/discussion-between-datenwolf-and-viraj)

Answer (score 0):

i think your distortion is due to your changeSize(...) function: you calculate the aspect ratio of of your window, but you do not use it. Have a look at the code where you stole this snippet from :)

Do you change resolution of your screen when switching to fullscreen mode? If you do, it is very likely that a pixel is not square anymore, so you will need the actual aspect ratio of your screen.