# Game hangs while updating level in Brick Breaker. - Open GL.

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I've written a simple brick breaker game using OpenGL and OpenGLUT. Everthing works as it should, except, when a level gets over, the game hangs. Any idea why ?
I tried telling it to reset all parameters, but nothing works. :(

```
#include <GL/openglut.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#define RADIUS    0.025
#define P_LENGTH  0.3
using namespace std;
int WIDTH     = 900,
    HEIGHT    = 650,
    lives     = 3,
    SCORE     = 0,
    LEVEL     = 2,
    BRICK_ROW = 10,
    BRICK_COL = 9;
double x_brick[10][10],
       y_brick[10][10],
       P_XPOS = 0,
       P_YPOS = -0.8,
       x_pos = 0,
       y_pos = -0.75,
       win_aspect,
       SPEED = 0;
bool show[10][10],
     phit_center = false, 
     phit_corner = false,
     game_over   = false,
     RIGHT       = true,
     LEFT        = false,
     UP          = true,
     DOWN        = false,
     started     = false,
     hit         = false;
char life = '0';
void user_input(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
     if(key == 13)
            started = true; 
}
void b_draw()
{
      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      for(int a = 0; a < BRICK_COL; a++)
      {
              for(int b = 0; b < BRICK_ROW; b++)
              {
                      switch(b)
                      {
                      case 0:
                           glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
                           break;
                      case 1:
                           glColor3f(1.0,0.9,0.1);
                           break;
                      case 2:
                           glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
                           break;
                      case 3:
                           glColor3f(0.11,0.56,1.0);
                           break;
                      default:
                              glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
                      }
                      if(show[b][a] == true)
                      {
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a]*win_aspect,y_brick[b][a]);
                                    glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a]*win_aspect,(y_brick[b][a] - 0.10)); 
                                    glVertex2f((x_brick[b][a]+0.2)*win_aspect,(y_brick[b][a] - 0.10));
                                    glVertex2f((x_brick[b][a]+0.2)*win_aspect,y_brick[b][a]);  
                      }
              }
      }
      glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
      glEnd();
}

void Set_Level(int level)
{
     int R_Limit = 0;
     switch(level)
     {
       case 1:
          for(int a = 0; a < BRICK_ROW; a++)
          {
            for(int b = 0; b < BRICK_COL; b++)
            {
                    show[a][b] = 1;
            }
          }
          break;
       case 2:
          for(int a = 0; a < BRICK_ROW/2; a++)
          {
                  for(int b = 0; b < BRICK_COL; b++)
                  {
                    if(b >= BRICK_COL/2 - R_Limit && b<=BRICK_COL/2 + R_Limit)
                    show[a][b] = true;
                  }
                  R_Limit++;
          }    
          R_Limit = BRICK_ROW/2;
          for(int a = BRICK_ROW/2; a <= BRICK_ROW; a++)
          {
                  for(int b = 0; b <= BRICK_COL; b++)
                  {
                          if(b >= BRICK_COL/2 - R_Limit && b <= BRICK_COL/2 + R_Limit)
                          show[a][b] = true;                  
                  }
                  R_Limit--;
          }
          break;
       case 3:
            for(int a = 0; a <= BRICK_COL/2; a++)
            {
                    show[a][a] = true;
            }
            for(int a = BRICK_COL; a >= BRICK_COL/2; a--)
            {
                    show[BRICK_COL - a - 1][a] = true;
            }
            break;
     }              
}
bool all_gone()
{
     int local_flag = 0;
     for(int a = 0; a < BRICK_COL; a++)
     {
             for(int b = 0; b < BRICK_ROW; b++)
             {
                     if(show[b][a] == true)
                     {
                                   return false;
                                   local_flag = 1;
                                   break;
                     }
                     if(local_flag)
                                   break;
             }
     }

     return true;
}
void c_draw()
{
     glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
     glVertex2f(x_pos,y_pos);
     for (float angle = 0; angle < (10); angle+=0.01)
     {
         glVertex2f((x_pos + sin(angle) * RADIUS), (y_pos + (cos(angle)) * RADIUS));
     }
     glEnd();
}
bool crashed()
{
     if(y_pos < P_YPOS - 0.1)
              return true;
     else return false;
}
void c_move()
{
      if(UP && RIGHT)
      {
           x_pos += SPEED;
           y_pos += SPEED;       
      }
      if(UP && LEFT)
      {
            x_pos -= SPEED;
            y_pos += SPEED;
      }
      if(DOWN && RIGHT)
      {
              x_pos += SPEED;
              y_pos -= SPEED;
      }
      if(DOWN && LEFT)
      {
              x_pos -= SPEED;
              y_pos -= SPEED;
      }
}
void p_draw()
{
     glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                      glVertex2f(P_XPOS-P_LENGTH, P_YPOS);
                      glVertex2f(P_XPOS+P_LENGTH, P_YPOS);
                      glVertex2f(P_XPOS+P_LENGTH, P_YPOS-0.05);
                      glVertex2f(P_XPOS-P_LENGTH, P_YPOS-0.05);
     glEnd();
}
void SET_BRICKS(int level)
{
     switch(level)
     {
                  case 1:
                       BRICK_ROW = 4;
                       break;
                  case 2:
                       BRICK_ROW = 7;
                       break;
                  case 3:
                       BRICK_ROW = 7;
                       break;
     }
}
void BallLoop()
{
     const int   win_width  = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH),
                 win_height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
     win_aspect = (float)win_width/(float)win_height;
     glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0);
     glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);
     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     glOrtho(-win_aspect, win_aspect, -1, 1, -1, 1);
     c_draw();
     b_draw();
     p_draw();
     life = '0' + lives;
     if(started && lives > 0)
                c_move();
     glFlush();
     glutSwapBuffers();
     glutPostRedisplay();
}
void GameLogic()
{  
      if(all_gone())
      {
                         x_pos = 0;
                         y_pos = -0.7;
                         LEVEL++;
                         for(int a = 0; a < BRICK_ROW; a++)
                         {
                                 for(int b = 0; b <BRICK_COL; b++)
                                 {
                                         show[a][b] = true;
                                 }
                         }
                         phit_center = false, 
                         phit_corner = false,
                         game_over   = false,
                         RIGHT       = true,
                         LEFT        = false,
                         UP          = true,
                         DOWN        = false,
                         started     = false,
                         hit         = false;
                         SET_BRICKS(LEVEL);
                         Set_Level(LEVEL);
      }         
      if(x_pos >= win_aspect)
      {
               RIGHT = 0;
               LEFT = 1;
      }
      else if(x_pos <= -win_aspect)
      {
           RIGHT = 1;
           LEFT = 0;
      }
      if(y_pos >= 1-RADIUS || hit )
      {
                  UP = 0;
                  DOWN = 1;
      }
      else if(y_pos <= -1+RADIUS || hit )
      {
           UP = 1;
           DOWN = 0;
      }
      hit = false;
      int flag = 1;
      for(int a = 0; a < BRICK_COL; a++)
      {
             for(int b =0; b < BRICK_ROW; b++)
             {
                     if(x_pos >= x_brick[b][a]*win_aspect && x_pos <= (x_brick[b][a] + 0.2)*win_aspect)
                     {
                              if(y_pos <= y_brick[b][a] && y_pos >= y_brick[b][a] - 0.1)
                              {
                                       if(show[b][a] == 1)
                                       {
                                                     show[b][a] = 0;
                                                     flag = 0;
                                                     hit = true;
                                                     break;
                                       }
                              }
                     }
             }
             if(flag == 0)
                     break;
      }
      phit_corner = false;
      phit_center = false;
      if(x_pos <= (P_XPOS + P_LENGTH - 0.05)&& x_pos >= (P_XPOS - P_LENGTH - 0.05))
      {
              if(y_pos <= P_YPOS)
              {
                       phit_center = true;
              }
      }
      else if((x_pos >=(P_XPOS + P_LENGTH - 0.05) && x_pos <= (P_XPOS + P_LENGTH)) || (x_pos <= (P_XPOS - P_LENGTH + 0.05) && x_pos >= P_XPOS - P_LENGTH))
      {
               if(y_pos <= P_YPOS)
               {
                        phit_corner = true;
               }
      }
      if(phit_center)
      {
                     DOWN = false;
                     UP   = true;
      }
      if(phit_corner)
      {
                     if(LEFT)
                     {
                             LEFT  = false;
                             RIGHT = true;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         RIGHT = false;
                         LEFT  = true;
                     }
                     UP   = false;
                     DOWN = true;
      }
      if(crashed())
      {           
                 x_pos = 0;
                 y_pos = -0.7;
                 started = false;
                 UP      = true;
                 RIGHT   = true;
                 DOWN    = false;
                 LEFT    = false;    
      }
      BallLoop();     
}
void ArrowKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
     if(key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT && P_XPOS >= -0.9*win_aspect)
     {
                           for(float a = 0; a < 0.05; a+= 0.001)
                           {
                                      P_XPOS -=0.002;
                                      GameLogic();
                           }
                           if(!started)
                           started = true;
     }
     if(key==GLUT_KEY_RIGHT && P_XPOS <= 0.9*win_aspect)
     {
                            for(float a = 0; a < 0.05; a+= 0.001)
                            {
                                      P_XPOS +=0.002;
                                      GameLogic();
                            }
                            if(!started)
                            started = true;
     }
}
void Init_Game()
{

    int c = 0;
    for(float a = -0.94; c < BRICK_COL; a+=0.21)
    {         

              for(int b = 0; b <= BRICK_ROW; b++)
              {
                      x_brick[b][c] = a;

              }
              c++;
    }
    c = 0;
    for(float a = 0.99; c < BRICK_ROW; a-=0.11)
    {
              for(int  b = 0; b < BRICK_COL; b++)
              {
                       y_brick[c][b] = a;
              }
              c++;
    }
}
void set_speed()
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int a = 1; a < 99999999LLU; a+= 1)
    {
            ;
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    SPEED = (double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    SPEED /= 800;
 }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    set_speed();
    Init_Game();
    SET_BRICKS(LEVEL);
    Set_Level(LEVEL);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);                    
    glutCreateWindow("Brick Breaker - By Viraj");
    glutKeyboardFunc(user_input);
    glutSpecialFunc(ArrowKeys);
    glutIdleFunc(GameLogic);
    glutDisplayFunc(BallLoop);
    glutMainLoop(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What loop is it stuck in when you break in the debugger?

Comment: I'm using Dev-C++ and can't get the debugger to work. -.- . After all the bricks have been destroyed, it loads a new level but te ball doesn't move at all!

Comment: I heard [tag:dev-c++] was not recommended.

Comment: Well, there's your problem .If you are using a broken tool that prevents you from debugging, get a tool that isn't broken. [Read this about Dev-C++](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info)

Comment: Don't use Dev-C++, it's a piece of crap, not an IDE.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus what IDE do you recommend, then ? I tried using eclipse and netbeans, but they were too impossible to setup. And I just didn't like Code::Blocks for some reason. The multicoloured editor seemed childish

Comment: @viraj: *Anything* but Dev-C++. The link I posted gives you plenty of other options, and honestly, if you have the choice between an editor you dislike because of its color scheme, versus an editor **which doesn't have a debugger**, pick the first one. Saying "I chose to use a broken tool because I liked its color scheme best" just means "I haven't even tried debugging my code", which in turn means people here are unlikely to want to help you. If you need help setting up Eclipse, ask about it here on SO. Don't just say "I'll keep using the IDE that doesn't work instead"

Comment: @viraj: Anything else than Dev-Crap. C::B and Eclipse are both good choices. Visual Studio, too. Or just any decent text editor, really.

Comment: Unfortunately adding a question that does this will always get it closed. "Help, Code broken, here it is *regurgitates code*"

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus using Eclpise now. A bit irritating to have to link to libraries, everytime you start a new project, but oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the corrected version of your code I posted as answer to your original question. [Brick Breaker help. circles, paddles, and awkward bouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826000/brick-breaker-help-circles-paddles-and-awkward-bouncing/6826353#6826353)

Reposting the GLFW version here again, for simplicity:

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define RADIUS 0.025

#define RATIO (4./3.)

bool show[5][10];
float x_brick[4][9];
float y_brick[4][9];

const float SpeedFactor = 1.;

float paddle_x = 0;
float paddle_y = -0.8;
float paddle_speed = 0;
const float PaddleSpeedFactor = 3.;

bool phit_center = false, phit_corner = false;
bool game_over = false;

float speed_x = 0.;
float speed_y = 0.;

float x_pos;
float y_pos;
int lifes = 0;

void draw_bricks()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
            if (show[b][a] == 1) {
                glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a], y_brick[b][a]);
                glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a], y_brick[b][a] - 0.10);
                glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a] + 0.2,
                       y_brick[b][a] - 0.10);
                glVertex2f(x_brick[b][a] + 0.2, y_brick[b][a]);
            }
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}

void ball_draw()
{
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(x_pos, y_pos);
    for (float angle = 0; angle < (10); angle += 0.01) {
        glVertex2f((x_pos + sin(angle) * RADIUS),
               (y_pos + (cos(angle)) * RADIUS));
    }
    glEnd();
}

bool brick_hit()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
            if (x_pos >= x_brick[b][a]
                && x_pos <= x_brick[b][a] + 0.2) {
                if (y_pos <= y_brick[b][a]
                    && y_pos >= y_brick[b][a] - 0.1) {
                    if (show[b][a] == 1) {
                        show[b][a] = 0;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool crashed()
{
    if (y_pos < paddle_y - 0.05)
        return true;

    return false;
}

void paddle_hit()
{
    phit_corner = false;
    phit_center = false;
    if (x_pos <= paddle_x + 0.13 && x_pos >= paddle_x - 0.13) {
        if (y_pos <= paddle_y) {
            phit_center = true;
        }
    } else if ((x_pos >= paddle_x + 0.13 && x_pos <= paddle_x + 0.2) ||
           (x_pos <= paddle_x - 0.13 && x_pos >= paddle_x - 0.2)) {
        if (y_pos <= paddle_y) {
            phit_corner = true;
        }
    }
}

void paddle_move(float dT)
{

    if (paddle_x < RATIO && paddle_x > -RATIO)
        paddle_x += paddle_speed * PaddleSpeedFactor * dT;

    if (paddle_x > 1.) {
        paddle_x = 1.;
        paddle_speed = 0.;
    }

    if (paddle_x < -1.) {
        paddle_x = -1.;
        paddle_speed = 0.;
    }
}

void ball_move(float dT)
{
    x_pos += speed_x * dT;
    y_pos += speed_y * dT;

    if (brick_hit()) {
        speed_y *= -1;
    }

    if (x_pos >= (RATIO - RADIUS) || x_pos <= (-RATIO + RADIUS)) {
        speed_x *= -1;
    }

    if (y_pos >= (1. - RADIUS)) {
        speed_y *= -1;
    }

    paddle_hit();
    if (phit_center) {
        speed_y *= -1;
    speed_x += 0.5 * paddle_speed;
    }
    if (phit_corner) {
        speed_x = -speed_x + 0.2 * paddle_speed;
        speed_y *= -1;
    }

    if( (speed_x * speed_x + speed_y * speed_y) > 0.001 ) {
        float k = 1./sqrt(speed_x * speed_x + speed_y * speed_y);
        speed_x *= k;
        speed_y *= k;
    }
}

void paddle_draw()
{
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(paddle_x - 0.2, paddle_y);
    glVertex2f(paddle_x + 0.2, paddle_y);
    glVertex2f(paddle_x + 0.2, paddle_y - 0.05);
    glVertex2f(paddle_x - 0.2, paddle_y - 0.05);
    glEnd();
}

void set_xy();

void reset_game()
{
    set_xy();
    lifes = 3;
    speed_x = 0;
    speed_y = 0;
    x_pos = 0;
    y_pos = -0.7;
    paddle_speed = 0;
    paddle_x = 0;
}

void step_game(float dT)
{
    if(!lifes)
        return;

    paddle_move(dT * SpeedFactor);
    ball_move(dT * SpeedFactor);

    if (crashed()) {
        lifes--;
        speed_x = 0;
        speed_y = 0;
        x_pos = 0;
        y_pos = -0.7;
    }
}

static float frandom(float a, float b)
{
    return a + (b - a) * (float)random() / (float)RAND_MAX;
}

void launch_ball()
{
    if(!lifes)
        return;

    speed_y = 1.;
    speed_x = frandom(-1., 1.);

    float k = 1./sqrt(speed_x * speed_x + speed_y + speed_y);
    speed_x *= k;
    speed_y *= k;
}

void keyboard(int key, int action)
{
    switch(key) 
    {
    case GLFW_KEY_ENTER:
        launch_ball();
        break;

    case GLFW_KEY_ESC:
        reset_game();
        break;

    case GLFW_KEY_LEFT:
        switch(action) {
        case GLFW_PRESS:
            paddle_speed = -1.;
            break;

        case GLFW_RELEASE:
            paddle_speed = 0;
            break;
        } break;

    case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT:
        switch(action) {
        case GLFW_PRESS:
            paddle_speed = 1.;
            break;

        case GLFW_RELEASE:
            paddle_speed = 0;
            break;
        } break;
    }
}

void set_xy()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
            show[a][b] = 1;
        }
    }
    int c = 0;
    for (float a = -0.94; c <= 8; a += 0.21, c++) {
        for (int b = 0; b <= 5; b++) {
            x_brick[b][c] = a;

        }
    }
    int d = 0;
    for (float s = 0.99; d <= 3; s -= 0.11, d++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
            y_brick[d][r] = s;
        }
    }
}

float display()
{
    int win_width;
    int win_height;
    glfwGetWindowSize(&win_width, &win_height);
    const float win_aspect = (float)win_width / (float)win_height;

    glfwSetTime(0.);

    glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (win_aspect > RATIO) {
        glOrtho(-win_aspect, win_aspect, -1., 1., -1., 1.);
    } else {
        glOrtho(-RATIO, RATIO, -RATIO / win_aspect, RATIO / win_aspect,
            -1., 1.);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glClearColor(0., 0., 1., 1.);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glVertex2f(-RATIO, -1);
    glVertex2f(RATIO, -1);
    glVertex2f(RATIO, 1);
    glVertex2f(-RATIO, 1);
    glEnd();

    draw_bricks();
    paddle_draw();

    ball_draw();

    glfwSwapBuffers();
    return glfwGetTime();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    srandom(time(0));

    set_xy();

    if( GL_FALSE == glfwInit() )
        return -1;

    if( GL_FALSE == glfwOpenWindow(800, 600, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW) )
        return -2;

    glfwSetWindowTitle("Viraj's Brick Breaker - GLFW version by datenwolf");
    glfwSetKeyCallback(keyboard);

    reset_game();

    while( glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED) ) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        float const dT = display();
        step_game(dT);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm just telling this, because the code you posted above is (again) an utter mess. Also notice how I count down the lifes, and introduced a function `reset_game` that will put things back to starting conditions.

BTW: Your coding style is a mess. It looks like you've done a lot of BASIC (GW-BASIC or QBASIC programming) and are still mentally stuck in that world.

For example you should reset the game field through a single entry function, that then calls specialized functions for each reset step. Then you just call that reset function, instead of trying to keep track of all variables.

I understand that the new code in your question has new features, but you still need to restructure a few things.

One of the biggest mistakes of yours is, that you still mix input with animation:

```
void ArrowKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
     if(key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT && P_XPOS >= -0.9*win_aspect)
     {
                       for(float a = 0; a < 0.05; a+= 0.001)
                       {
                                  P_XPOS -=0.002;
                                  GameLogic();
                       }
```

That inner for loop will animate the paddle in reaction to the key, and while this animation happens all further **user input will pile up**, leading to strange movements. Never do this. In a input handler set some state variable, that influences the GameLogic in the idle loop. But never directly animate from the input handler!

Please take a look at my code, compile it, execute it. And try to understand the separation between game logic, rendering and input processing.

Comment: How'd you guess that ? I'm still at school so I learnt QBasic first, then VisualBasic after that, before moving on to C++. Bycoding style, i assume you mean the way i oeaveline spaces and use the { } ? Also, you stopped replying on chat.  I tried to use GLFW on Dev C++ and installed the Dev pack on DevCpp but every time I compile the code, it compiles successfully but no window appears. After about two minutes, the antivirus program flags it as a virus. Returning to the program, Ive attempted to do the same thing as your reset_game function, but internally. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: By coding style I mean, how you use variables, functions and the like. Your code is structured like a BASIC program. Many C coders would take this an insult;) I didn't react to chat, because I was offline, until right now.

Comment: @viraj: The biggest telltale sign, sonebody is mentally stuck in the BASIC world is the use of global variables. While there's nothing wrong with placing global state in global variables, data passed between functions should be passed by parameters.